# IOS - No "touchend" event for not fullscreen webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview, uiwebview

"onTouchEnd" is not firing when touch ends outside of webview.
Compile with XCode 6, iOs 8, iPhone 6

I have next layout:

```
|Navigation TAB|
|Left view|Web view|Right view|
|page view|
```

I can receive all touch events, when touch starts and ends, in web view.
But if I start touch in webview and then move touch outside of it, I would stop receiving touchmove events as soon as I leave webview border, and no touchend event is received.

Code fot test html file:

```
  <head>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#CC6"
      ontouchmove="console.info('move');"
      ontouchstart="console.info('start');"
      ontouchend="console.info('end');"
      ontouchcancelled="console.info('canceled');"
  >
  <h1>This is a test</h1>
  <p> Lore ip sum </p>
  </body>
```

Code of "viewDidLoad" function

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mainView.bounds];

[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.webView setAlpha:1];

/* Disable scrolling of web view */
for (id subview in [self.webView subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView*)subview).bounces = NO;
    }
}

self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor]; //[UIColor colorWithRed:(45.0/255.0) green:(50.0/255.0) blue:(53.0/255.0) alpha:1];
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.mainView addSubview:self.webView];


NSString * localHtmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localHtmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 



[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

How this can be fixed? Is there are some configuration that I missed?

Complete source code can be found here: https://github.com/Daraku/WebViewBug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been strugling with the same for past 30minutes, in the end i've decided to implement a timeout which is getting restored with every `touchmove` and starts on `touchstart`, and gets cleared on `touchend`. Timeout is for lets say `1500ms`, and if i don't get `touchend` fired from within the webview as it should, i fire it when the timeout ends.

Hope i made a point. Its not perfect but serves as partial fix. In my case hackaround for iScroll( _execEvent('scrollCancel') )

Comment: setTimeout - hack, is what I end-up using (although i use much smaller time values). Looks like, there are no proper solution :(

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I've embedded a webview in a native app. The native app has a header of say 60 px and below it sits the webview.

When swiping up from the webview and releasing your finger on the header the 'touchend' event doesn't propagate to the webview.

I found that the Y coordinate on the 'touchmove' event is negative when leaving the webview at the top so I leverage that fact by listening to it and programmatically triggering a touchend event. Works like a boss!

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
if (e.changedTouches[0].pageY < 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('touchend'));
}
```

}, false);

Here's a gist of the same code: https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/70b96fce47fa7bf7a34f03e3a2ecb85f

Comment: unfortunately, I need to catch it when finger leaves physical screen, not WebView area.

Comment: this was exactly what I was searching for, because only over the iOS statusbar the touchend didn't get called. I still need call touchend when a phone call comes in, because this is causing an overlay which breaks the touchend event as well.